# What does the latter in the ram description mean?

Tags: memory

I am trying to pick ram for my laptop. I can see these types of ram on the site.

```
Ddr4 2133 pc4 17000
Ddr4 2133 pc4 17000s
Ddr4 2133 pc4 17000u
Ddr4 2133 pc4 17066r
Ddr4 2133 pc3 17066
```

What does the latter at the end or lack of it mean? Which one should I choose? Also, about the 3 or 4 after pc. What is it supposed to mean? Is bigger number better?

Comment: Voting to close:  echnical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on Super User.

Comment: I don't see this as troubleshooting. The OG is asking what something means on a device. However, you're correct about it violating the purpose of this SE since it's used for recommendation.

Comment: Even though I answered your question below, I'm going to vote to migrate this question.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the "pc3" is a typo, and it should be "pc4".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's points out the type of the RAM :

```
The "R" is for Registered which is usually used in servers.
The "U" stands for unbuffered non ECC.
The "E" stands for unbuffered ECC (not registred)
The "S" for SO-DIMM, a format of DIMM's used for laptops :)
"L" is for Low Voltage
```

Those are the ones I know.